# Алгоритм Дейкстры + Builder pattern - Java

Tags: java, алгоритм

Дали задание реализовать паттерн Builder для алгоритма Дейкстры, чтобы объект `Graph` был *immutable*, и были методы нахождения кратчайшего пути. Я написал это недоразумение, но я очень недоволен кодом, подскажите как это можно оптимизировать или изменить чтобы при создании графа можно было просто сделать `Graph graph = new Graph().edge(1, 2 ,44).edge(1, 3, 65)...build();`

```
public class Edge {
    private final Vertex start;
    private final Vertex finish;
    private final int weight;

    public Edge(String laneId, Vertex source, Vertex destination, int weight) {
        this.start = source;
        this.finish = destination;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Vertex getFinish() {
        return finish;
    }

    public Vertex getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

}

public class Vertex {
    final private String id;
    final private String name;

    public Vertex(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Vertex other = (Vertex) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}

public class Dejkstra {
    private final List<Vertex> nodes;
    private final List<Edge> edges;
    private Set<Vertex> settledNodes;
    private Set<Vertex> unSettledNodes;
    private Map<Vertex, Vertex> predecessors;
    private Map<Vertex, Integer> distance;

    public Dejkstra(Graph graph) {
        this.nodes = new ArrayList<Vertex>(graph.getVertexes());
        this.edges = new ArrayList<Edge>(graph.getEdges());
    }

    public void execute(Vertex source) {
        settledNodes = new HashSet<Vertex>();
        unSettledNodes = new HashSet<Vertex>();
        distance = new HashMap<Vertex, Integer>();
        predecessors = new HashMap<Vertex, Vertex>();
        distance.put(source, 0);
        unSettledNodes.add(source);
        while (unSettledNodes.size() > 0) {
            Vertex node = getMinimum(unSettledNodes);
            settledNodes.add(node);
            unSettledNodes.remove(node);
            findMinimalDistances(node);
        }
    }

    private void findMinimalDistances(Vertex node) {
        List<Vertex> adjacentNodes = getNeighbors(node);
        for (Vertex target : adjacentNodes) {
            if (getShortestDistance(target) > getShortestDistance(node)
                    + getDistance(node, target)) {
                distance.put(target, getShortestDistance(node)
                        + getDistance(node, target));
                predecessors.put(target, node);
                unSettledNodes.add(target);
            }
        }
    }

    private int getDistance(Vertex node, Vertex target) {
        for (Edge edge : edges) {
            if (edge.getStart().equals(node)
                    && edge.getFinish().equals(target)) {
                return edge.getWeight();
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Should not happen");
    }

    private List<Vertex> getNeighbors(Vertex node) {
        List<Vertex> neighbors = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Edge edge : edges) {
            if (edge.getStart().equals(node)
                    && !isSettled(edge.getFinish())) {
                neighbors.add(edge.getFinish());
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

    private Vertex getMinimum(Set<Vertex> vertexes) {
        Vertex minimum = null;
        for (Vertex vertex : vertexes) {
            if (minimum == null) {
                minimum = vertex;
            } else {
                if (getShortestDistance(vertex) < getShortestDistance(minimum)) {
                    minimum = vertex;
                }
            }
        }
        return minimum;
    }

    private boolean isSettled(Vertex vertex) {
        return settledNodes.contains(vertex);
    }

    private int getShortestDistance(Vertex destination) {
        Integer d = distance.get(destination);
        if (d == null) {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else {
            return d;
        }
    }

    public LinkedList<Vertex> getPath(Vertex target) {
        LinkedList<Vertex> path = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
        Vertex step = target;
        if (predecessors.get(step) == null) {
            return null;
        }
        path.add(step);
        while (predecessors.get(step) != null) {
            step = predecessors.get(step);
            path.add(step);
        }
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }
}

public class Graph {
    private final List<Vertex> vertexes;
    private final List<Edge> edges;

    public List<Edge> getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }
    public List<Vertex> getVertexes(){
        return vertexes;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private List<Vertex> vertexes;
        private List<Edge> edges;


        public Builder edge(List<Vertex> vertexes, List<Edge> edges) {
            this.vertexes = vertexes;
            this.edges = edges;
            return this;
        }

        public Graph build() {
            return new Graph(this);
        }
    }

    Graph(Builder builder) {
        vertexes = builder.vertexes;
        edges = builder.edges;
    }

}

public class Test {
    private List<Vertex> nodes;
    private List<Edge> edges;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testExcute() {
        nodes = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            Vertex location = new Vertex("Node_" + i, "Node_" + i);
            nodes.add(location);
        }

        addLane("Edge_0", 1, 2, 70);
        addLane("Edge_1", 1, 3, 140);
        addLane("Edge_2", 1, 4, 120);
        addLane("Edge_3", 2, 5, 130);
        addLane("Edge_4", 3, 4, 80);
        addLane("Edge_5", 3, 6, 100);
        addLane("Edge_6", 4, 5, 140);
        addLane("Edge_7", 4, 6, 100);
        addLane("Edge_8", 4, 8, 150);
        addLane("Edge_9", 5, 7, 150);
        addLane("Edge_10", 6, 7, 170);
        addLane("Edge_11", 6, 8, 70);
        addLane("Edge_12", 7, 8, 90);

        Graph graph = new Graph.Builder().edge(nodes, edges).build();
        Dejkstra dijkstra = new Dejkstra(graph);
        dijkstra.execute(nodes.get(0));
        LinkedList<Vertex> path = dijkstra.getPath(nodes.get(7));

        assertNotNull(path);
        assertTrue(path.size() > 0);

        for (Vertex vertex : path) {
            System.out.println(vertex);
        }

    }

    private void addLane(String laneId, int sourceLocNo, int destLocNo,
                         int duration) {
        Edge lane = new Edge(laneId, nodes.get(sourceLocNo), nodes.get(destLocNo), duration);
        edges.add(lane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Аналогично устроено в `ViewPropertyAnimator`:

```
view.animate().scaleX(0).scaleY(0).setDuration(500).start();
```

Хотите узнать как? [Исходник](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.java)